# pandas add a new column category where existing column between value X and value Y

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to add a new column that categorises an existing column based on its values from one value up until another value down the column.

This is my DataFrame:

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

csvStringIO = StringIO("""Account,Revenue
,
Assets,
Advance on Grant,2345
Co-funding Accrual,2436
Trade And Other Receivable,234
Conversion Spend,235
GCBF,2364
Cash And Cash Equivalents,75
Total Current Assets,75
,
"Property, Plant And Equipment",134
Intangible Assets,523
Investment Assets,254
Loan Assets,273
Total Non Current Assets,734
Total Assets,27235
,
Liabilities,
Trade And Other Payable,2345
Grant Accruals,7345
Other Accruals,623
Provision For Liabilities And Charges,2346
Total Current Liabilities,266432
,
Total Liabilities,62346
,
Equity,
General reserve - Opening,2345
General reserve - Current,253
Revaluation reserve,6312
Share Capital,6312
Total Equity,623
Total Liabilities and Equity,5132
,""")
df = pd.read_csv(csvStringIO, sep=",") # read
```

```
                                  Account   Revenue
0                                     NaN       NaN
1                                  Assets       NaN
2                        Advance on Grant    2345.0
3                      Co-funding Accrual    2436.0
4              Trade And Other Receivable     234.0
5                        Conversion Spend     235.0
6                                    GCBF    2364.0
7               Cash And Cash Equivalents      75.0
8                    Total Current Assets      75.0
9                                     NaN       NaN
10          Property, Plant And Equipment     134.0
11                      Intangible Assets     523.0
12                      Investment Assets     254.0
13                            Loan Assets     273.0
14               Total Non Current Assets     734.0
15                           Total Assets   27235.0
16                                    NaN       NaN
17                            Liabilities       NaN
18                Trade And Other Payable    2345.0
19                         Grant Accruals    7345.0
20                         Other Accruals     623.0
21  Provision For Liabilities And Charges    2346.0
22              Total Current Liabilities  266432.0
23                                    NaN       NaN
24                      Total Liabilities   62346.0
25                                    NaN       NaN
26                                 Equity       NaN
27              General reserve - Opening    2345.0
28              General reserve - Current     253.0
29                    Revaluation reserve    6312.0
30                          Share Capital    6312.0
31                           Total Equity     623.0
32           Total Liabilities and Equity    5132.0
33                                    NaN       NaN
```

And I'd like to get a `Category` like so:

```
                                  Account   Revenue            Category
0                                     NaN       NaN                 NaN
1                                  Assets       NaN      current assets
2                        Advance on Grant    2345.0      current assets
3                      Co-funding Accrual    2436.0      current assets
4              Trade And Other Receivable     234.0      current assets
5                        Conversion Spend     235.0      current assets
6                                    GCBF    2364.0      current assets
7               Cash And Cash Equivalents      75.0      current assets
8                    Total Current Assets      75.0                 NaN
9                                     NaN       NaN                 NaN
10          Property, Plant And Equipment     134.0  non current assets
11                      Intangible Assets     523.0  non current assets
12                      Investment Assets     254.0  non current assets
13                            Loan Assets     273.0  non current assets
14               Total Non Current Assets     734.0                 NaN
15                           Total Assets   27235.0                 NaN
16                                    NaN       NaN                 NaN
17                            Liabilities       NaN         liabilities
18                Trade And Other Payable    2345.0         liabilities
19                         Grant Accruals    7345.0         liabilities
20                         Other Accruals     623.0         liabilities
21  Provision For Liabilities And Charges    2346.0         liabilities
22              Total Current Liabilities  266432.0                 NaN
23                                    NaN       NaN                 NaN
24                      Total Liabilities   62346.0                 NaN
25                                    NaN       NaN                 NaN
26                                 Equity       NaN              equity
27              General reserve - Opening    2345.0              equity
28              General reserve - Current     253.0              equity
29                    Revaluation reserve    6312.0              equity
30                          Share Capital    6312.0              equity
31                           Total Equity     623.0                 NaN
32           Total Liabilities and Equity    5132.0                 NaN
33                                    NaN       NaN                 NaN
```

i.e.

- `"current assets"` where `Account` = `"Assets"` up until (not including) `"Total Current Assets"`
- `"non current assets"` where `Account` = `"Property, Plant And Equipment"` up until (not including) `"Total Non Current Assets"`
- `"liabilities"` where `Account` = `"Liabilities"` up until (not including) `"Total Current Liabilities"`
- `"equity"` where `Account` = `"Equity"` up until (not including) `"Total Equity"`

Answer (score 0):

You could get the start and end row numbers for each category then populate the category name particularly for those rows.

Let's first define a function for this, and then call it for all the categories.

```py
def populate_range_of_rows(starting_row_value, ending_row_value, category):
    row_start = df.index[df['Account']==starting_row_value]
    row_end = df.index[df['Account']==ending_row_value]
    df.loc[row_start[0]:row_end[0]-1, 'Category'] = category

populate_range_of_rows('Assets', 'Total Current Assets', 'current assets')
populate_range_of_rows('Property, Plant And Equipment', 'Total Non Current Assets', 'non current assets')
populate_range_of_rows('Liabilities', 'Total Current Liabilities', 'liabilities')
populate_range_of_rows('Equity', 'Total Equity', 'equity')
```

This produces the output:

```
                                  Account   Revenue            Category
0                                     NaN       NaN                 NaN
1                                  Assets       NaN      current assets
2                        Advance on Grant    2345.0      current assets
3                      Co-funding Accrual    2436.0      current assets
4              Trade And Other Receivable     234.0      current assets
5                        Conversion Spend     235.0      current assets
6                                    GCBF    2364.0      current assets
7               Cash And Cash Equivalents      75.0      current assets
8                    Total Current Assets      75.0                 NaN
9                                     NaN       NaN                 NaN
10          Property, Plant And Equipment     134.0  non current assets
11                      Intangible Assets     523.0  non current assets
12                      Investment Assets     254.0  non current assets
13                            Loan Assets     273.0  non current assets
14               Total Non Current Assets     734.0                 NaN
15                           Total Assets   27235.0                 NaN
16                                    NaN       NaN                 NaN
17                            Liabilities       NaN         liabilities
18                Trade And Other Payable    2345.0         liabilities
19                         Grant Accruals    7345.0         liabilities
20                         Other Accruals     623.0         liabilities
21  Provision For Liabilities And Charges    2346.0         liabilities
22              Total Current Liabilities  266432.0                 NaN
23                                    NaN       NaN                 NaN
24                      Total Liabilities   62346.0                 NaN
25                                    NaN       NaN                 NaN
26                                 Equity       NaN              equity
27              General reserve - Opening    2345.0              equity
28              General reserve - Current     253.0              equity
29                    Revaluation reserve    6312.0              equity
30                          Share Capital    6312.0              equity
31                           Total Equity     623.0                 NaN
32           Total Liabilities and Equity    5132.0                 NaN
33                                    NaN       NaN                 NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a map to find the start of each category section then forward-fill to fully cover each section.  After that, remove the `Total` and `NaN` rows from the category column.

```
cat_map = {'Assets':'current assets',
           'Property, Plant And Equipment':'non current assets',
           'Liabilities':'liabilities',
           'Equity':'equity'}

tot_msk = df['Account'].isna() | df['Account'].str.contains('Total')
dfc = df.assign(category=df['Account'].map(cat_map).ffill().mask(tot_msk))
print(dfc)
```

**Result**

```
                                  Account   Revenue            category
0                                     NaN       NaN                 NaN
1                                  Assets       NaN      current assets
2                        Advance on Grant    2345.0      current assets
3                      Co-funding Accrual    2436.0      current assets
4              Trade And Other Receivable     234.0      current assets
5                        Conversion Spend     235.0      current assets
6                                    GCBF    2364.0      current assets
7               Cash And Cash Equivalents      75.0      current assets
8                    Total Current Assets      75.0                 NaN
9                                     NaN       NaN                 NaN
10          Property, Plant And Equipment     134.0  non current assets
11                      Intangible Assets     523.0  non current assets
12                      Investment Assets     254.0  non current assets
13                            Loan Assets     273.0  non current assets
14               Total Non Current Assets     734.0                 NaN
15                           Total Assets   27235.0                 NaN
16                                    NaN       NaN                 NaN
17                            Liabilities       NaN         liabilities
18                Trade And Other Payable    2345.0         liabilities
19                         Grant Accruals    7345.0         liabilities
20                         Other Accruals     623.0         liabilities
21  Provision For Liabilities And Charges    2346.0         liabilities
22              Total Current Liabilities  266432.0                 NaN
23                                    NaN       NaN                 NaN
24                      Total Liabilities   62346.0                 NaN
25                                    NaN       NaN                 NaN
26                                 Equity       NaN              equity
27              General reserve - Opening    2345.0              equity
28              General reserve - Current     253.0              equity
29                    Revaluation reserve    6312.0              equity
30                          Share Capital    6312.0              equity
31                           Total Equity     623.0                 NaN
32           Total Liabilities and Equity    5132.0                 NaN
33                                    NaN       NaN                 NaN
```